# Activate a function using a UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a button which allows the user to log out, once the user selects this button (“signoutButton”) then a UIAlertController appears asking the user if they want to sign out.

I have the code to sign a user out, and the code for a popup. However, I’m looking for a method of running the ‘signOut’ function once the user selects “Ok”. Any ideas?

Current Sign Out Method (User clicks the ‘Sign Out’ button, it signs them out and redirects to the homeviewcontroller)

```
@IBAction func signoutButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
do {
  try firebaseAuth.signOut()
    
    self.transitionToHome()
    
} catch let signOutError as NSError {
  print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
}
    }
```

I have this popup message (separate, however, I’d like it so once the user selects the ‘Ok’ button, they are then signed out and taken to the homeviewcontroller)

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Logout", message: "You have been sucessfully logged out, bye!", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

    // add an action (button)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))


    // show the alert
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        func transitionToHome() {
            
            let homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeViewController
            
            view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
            view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            
        }
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to place the signout and transition calls into the button handler, like this:

```
@IBAction func signoutButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Logout", message: "You have been sucessfully logged out, bye!", preferredStyle: .alert)

    // add an action (button)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            self.transitionToHome()
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }
    })


    // show the alert
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Super - thank you so much! I didn't realise you could add actions to UIAlerts :)